# Text area that varies depending on the selected item in the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dom

**Solved ... you can close ...**

I have a drop-down menu and a text-area in which I enter a written differently, depending on the item that is selected in the drop-down menu (dynamicly).

My html-php code is this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#copyright_titles').change(function () {                
                var isFirstSelected = $("#copyright_titles option:first-child" ).is(':selected');
                var isLastSelected = $("#copyright_titles option:last-child" ).is(':selected');

                if (isFirstSelected) {
                     $('#copyright_text').hide();
                     return;
                }

                $('#copyright_text').attr("readonly",isLastSelected?false:true);


                $.ajax({ type: "GET", url: "copyrights.xml", dataType: "xml", success: function(xml) {

                    $(xml).find('copyright').each(function() {

                      var copyright_title_selected = $("#copyright_titles option:selected").text();
                      var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                      var text = $(this).find('text').text();

                      if (title === copyright_title_selected) {
                          $('#copyright_text').text(text);
                      }

                    });
                  },
                  error: function(request, error, tipo_errore) { alert(error+': '+ tipo_errore); }
                });


                $('#copyright_text').show();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="test" action="test.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                    <td>Copyright:</td>
                    <td>
                        <select id='copyright_titles'>
                            <?php
                                $xml = simplexml_load_file('copyrights.xml');
                                $i = 0;
                                foreach($xml->copyright as $copyright)
                                {
                                    $i++;
                                    echo '<option value="copyright'.$i.'">'.$copyright->title.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td></td><td>
                        <textarea id='copyright_text' rows="6" cols="65" style="display:none"></textarea>
                    </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</body>
```

The texts are taken from this xml file:

```
<copyrights>
<copyright>
    <title>free</title>
    <text></text>
</copyright>
<copyright>
    <title>copyright1</title>
    <text>text1</text>
</copyright>
<copyright>
    <title>copyright2</title>
    <text>text2</text>
</copyright>
<copyright>
    <title>copyright3</title>
    <text>text3</text>
</copyright>
<copyright>
    <title>other</title>
    <text></text>
</copyright>
```

Comment: how large is your text?

Comment: It's a description of a copyright preimposed...

Answer (score 2):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/crustyashish/eYzSb/2/)

kidnly change select list as per ur code
HTML:

```
<select id="selectMe">
   <option value=""></option>
    <option value="option1">option1</option>
    <option value="option2">option2</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>

<textarea name="copyright_text" id="copyright_text" cols="20" rows="7">

</textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#selectMe').change(function () {

        $('#copyright_text').html($( "#selectMe option:selected" ).text());

    })
});
```

Comment: just add JS code into ur code file with <script> tag and also include some jquery file like jquery1.6 or jquery1.8 n blah blah

Comment: ...I can not answer because I do not have 10 reputation: (

Comment: I write this on bottom the form:  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#copyright_titles').change(function () {
                $('#copyright_text').html($( "#copyright_titles option:selected" ).text());
            })
        });
        </script>

Comment: but the text to put in the text-area, where I put it?

Comment: what u got in ur option value?? in my answer, the value in option is reflecting into textarea.

Comment: I solved it. Thanks...
But by default there is nothing.
Also, how should I do to make the text area is not visible by default (that is, with the first item selected) and not editable for all copyrights except the last one?

Comment: textarea is visible by default it just changing values according to ur options

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select name="copyright_titles" id='copyright_titles'>
                            <?php
                                $xml = simplexml_load_file('copyrights.xml');
                                $i = 0;
                                foreach($xml->copyright as $copyright)
                                {
                                    $i++;
                                    echo '<option value=".$copyright->text.">'.$copyright->title.'</option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>
```

//jquery function

```
$('#copyright_titles').change(function() { $('#copyright_text').attr('val',$('#copyright_titles').val()); });
```

Comment: I think he's after populating the textarea with the contents of the relevant `<text></text>` node from the XML file rather than the value of the drop down, which should be kept as the ID of the copyright entity.

Comment: please include jquery library before using this code.You can find the jquery lib [here](http://jquery.com/)

Comment: If you check the code.. he storing a counter value as id, text of the select is the title

Comment: I write this in tag <head>: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js">
            $('#copyright_titles').change(function() { $('#copyright_text').attr('val',$('#copyright_titles').val()); });
        </script>

Comment: but the text to put in the text-area, where I put it?

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to populate the `SELECT` list client side using [`jQuery.Get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) method rather than server side with PHP. You could asynchronously load the XML file and create an event handler to update the `TEXTAREA` value on change of the `SELECT`.